# -[NSPathStore2 objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a3fc60'

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I was preparing for a customCellView in a tableView. According to me, everything was perfect in .xib and methods. I am getting an exception in configuring the cell.

```
int listIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
    NSLog(@"outside");          
    cell.lblName.text = (NSString *) [[directoryContent objectAtIndex:listIndex] objectForKey:@"filesName"];
    cell.lblSize.text = (NSString *) [[directoryContent objectAtIndex:listIndex] objectForKey:@"filesSize"];
    cell.lblType.text = (NSString *) [[directoryContent objectAtIndex:listIndex] objectForKey:@"filesType"];
    return cell;
```

The compiler works till the `NSLog(@"outside");`. But it does not proceeds to the next line. I am terminated by the error

```
2010-11-15 20:32:28.623 iDataTraveller[5346:207] outside
2010-11-15 20:32:28.625 iDataTraveller[5346:207] -[NSPathStore2 objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f19cf0
2010-11-15 20:32:28.627 iDataTraveller[5346:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPathStore2 objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f19cf0'
```

Please help me to proceed.. Thank you in advance..

Comment: It seems to me that one of the object for the keys is missing, but not sure. Maybe you could try to change the way how is listIndex defined by constant which you are sure that should work.

Comment: Show all the code pertaining to the value of `directoryContent`.

Comment: Hi. I have posted my code in the next answer. Have a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wherever you created directoryContent, you stored the wrong object in it.
NSPathStore2 is an object that will be created if you use something like `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` on a NSString.
I guess you just stored the filename in the array but wanted to store a NSDictionary created from NSFileManagers `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`

Check that part were you add objects to directoryContent again.

Comment: Hi. I have posted my code in the next answer. Have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code. Have a look at this. Let me know what i am lagging.

```
- (void)listFiles {

    NSFileManager *fm =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *parentDirectory = @"/Users/akilan/Documents";
    NSArray *paths = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        error = nil;
    }
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.directoryContent = array;
    [array release];

    for (NSString *path in paths){
        filesName = [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        filesPath = [parentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        filesDirectory = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filesPath error:nil]];        
        filesSize = [filesDirectory objectForKey:NSFileSize];
        filesType = [path pathExtension];
        createdDate = [filesDirectory objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
        modifiedDate = [filesDirectory objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
        filesDirectory = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:filesPath,@"filesPath",
                          filesName,@"filesName",filesSize, @"filesSize", filesType, @"filesType",
                          createdDate,@"createdDate", modifiedDate,@"modifiedDate", nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", filesDirectory);
    }
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: none of that code adds the files directory to the directoryContent array . . .

Answer (score 0):

You have not retained `directoryContent`.

Can you show the code where `directoryContent` is created?

You can tell this because your error message says NSPathStore2 when it should be trying to call objectforKey on NSDictionary - this means that the memory where your dictionary was is not being used by something else :)

Comment: if this would be the case the exception would be `-[NSPathStore2 objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Hi. I have posted my code in the next answer. Have a look at that.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt - though I have seen cases where the directoryContent's memory is fine enough to point to another invalid memory location where an exception is raised you're almost 100% correct - we've leaked the contents of the array, not the array itself.